# Bootstrap displaying tablet size site when tablet resolution is 1280x800

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tablet

I'm testing a website made using Bootstrap 3.3.0 on my Asus Memopad 8 tablet. The resolution on the tablet is 1280x800. For some reason when I visit the site on this tablet the media query to display a site on a small device kicks in. Why is this happening when the media query for sizes over 1200 wide should be kicking in instead? This happens whether I specify to get the desktop or mobile version of the site.

IPad II has a resolution of 1024x768 so in landscape mode I should get the desktop version of the site but it also only shows the mobile version of the site.

Comment: You sure your tablet is *exactly* 1200 px wide?

Comment: Tablet is 1280 wide. Bootstraps maximum media query is 1200.

Comment: Perhaps these resources might help... Here is a Bookmarklet that shows which media queries are being used and the screen size: https://github.com/sparkbox/mediaQueryBookmarklet Here is an online resource where you can resize the window to exact pixel sizes: http://responsivepx.com/

Comment: Asus specs said 1280 wide but when I use a script that measures the viewport its less than 1000 wide